# Angular binding not updating properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

What I'm trying to do is rather simple, I would think. I am trying to update a few values linked to an object in my controller based on what is selected from a select box. Hopefully you guys can shed some light on what I'm doing wrong.

My controller instantiates the object (which I'm not sure if I actually need to do):

```
$scope.newInvoice = {}
```

Then my html provides a dropdown box with a list of invoices that can be selected and the table **should** auto updated with the values from the selected invoices, but it does not:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <select ng-model="newInvoice">
            <option ng-repeat="name in names" value="{{name}}">{{name.Name}}</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>TBD</td>
    <td>{{newInvoice.PoNumber}}</td>
    <td>{{newInvoice.Price | currency}}</td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" ng-model="newInvoice.Quantity"/>
    </td>
    <td>{{newInvoice.Price * newInvoice.Quantity | currency}}</td>
</tr>
```

Essentially, the table does not fill in with the values provided from the select box. But if I print `newInvoice` to the screen with `<pre>{{newInvoice}}</pre>` I can see that `newInvoice` does in fact have all of the values, all properly named. So it would seem that the select box is binding well with the model. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ng-options` instead of rendering options using `ng-repeat`, because when you use `ng-repeat` to render `options`, it does fill `value` attribute with `object` but that has been `stringified`. Where as if you use `ng-options` behind the scene it does assign actual object value to mentioned `ng-model` variable.

**Markup**

```
<select ng-model="newInvoice" ng-options="name.Name for name in names"></select>
```

Comment: @wut Glad to help you on that.. Thanks :-)